# Problem with external monitor and MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, display, screen, projector

I cannot connect my MacBook Air to an external monitor. But I am able to connect it to a projector, without any difficulty. My computer detects the external monitor but cannot connect to it. The screen is just black

- I have tried everything in the System Preferences > Display > Resolution
  category. Does not work, but any clue will help!
- I have upgraded everything on my Mac, so that it is now OS
  X El Capitan.
- I have tried to deconnect and reconnent the cable connecting to the screen.
- Other MacBook Air work with the monitors I want to use, and they all work.
- I have tried the sleep-mode to get it to detect the mac/screen.
- I have tried changing the VGA cable.

I have tried almost everything, what am I missing?

Comment: Are you connecting using 100Hz for example on a 60 Hz monitor? Does a different monitor work?

Comment: I have tried with 2 different monitors and it is the same problem. I was suggested by apple support that it might be a software issue, but I dont know what kind of software that should be?

And I dont know how to find out about the 60Hz and 100Hz :/

Comment: It appears to be 60Hz! found it :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you connecting using 100Hz for example on a 60 Hz monitor? The monitor will turn black then and appears to be disconnected.
There should be an option to cast it as a different Hz to your monitor.